# Why does the complement behave differently through printf?

Tags: c, variables, types, bitwise-operators, unsigned-char

I was reading a chapter on bitwise operators, I came across 1's complement operator program and decided to run it on Visual C++.

```
int main ()
{
   unsigned char c = 4, d;
   d = ~c;
   printf("%d\n", d);
}
```

It gives the valid output: `251`

Then instead of using `d` as a variable to hold the value of `~c`, I decided to directly print the value of `~c`.

```
int main ()
{
   unsigned char c=4;
   printf("%d\n", ~c);
}
```

It gives the output `-5`.

Why didn't it work?

Comment: Hint : 1's Complement of `4` is equivalent to two's complement representation of `-5`

Comment: it's [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), not [compliment](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/compliment)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc your complement deserves a compliment.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In this statement:

```
printf("%d",~c);
```

the `c` is converted to `int`<sup>1</sup> type **before** `~` (bitwise complement) operator is applied. This is because of *integer promotions*, that are invoked to operand of the `~`. In this case an object of `unsigned char` type is promoted to (signed) `int`, which is then (after `~` operator evaluation) used by `printf` function, with matching `%d` format specifier.

Notice that *default argument promotions* (as `printf` is a variadic function) does not play any role here, as object is already of type `int`.

On the other hand, in this code:

```
unsigned char c = 4, d;
d = ~c;
printf("%d", d);
```

the following steps occur:

- `c` is a subject to *integer promotions* because of `~` (in the same way, as described above)
- `~c` rvalue is evaluated as (signed) `int` value (e.g. `-5`)
- `d=~c` makes an implicit conversion from `int` to `unsigned char`, as `d` has such type. You may think of it as the same as `d = (unsigned char) ~c`. Notice that `d` cannot be negative (this is general rule for all unsigned types).
- `printf("%d", d);` invokes *default argument promotions*, thus `d` is converted to `int` and the (nonnegative) value is preserved (i.e. the `int` type can represent all values of `unsigned char` type).

---

<sup>1) assuming that `int` can represent all values of the `unsigned char` (see T.C.'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560245/why-do-these-programs-give-different-outputs/28560364#comment45480755_28560364) below), but it is *very* likely to happen in this way. More specifically, we assume that `INT_MAX >= UCHAR_MAX` holds. Typically the `sizeof(int) > sizeof(unsigned char)` holds and byte consist of eight bits. Otherwise the `c` would be converted to `unsigned int` (as by C11 subclause  §6.3.1.1/p2), and the format specifier should be also changed accordingly to `%u` in order to avoid getting an UB (C11 §7.21.6.1/p9).</sup>

Comment: But then this also happens in `d=~c`. The real diffrence then is the conversion (back) to `unsigend char` that happens in `d=~c`, but not in the `printf` call.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: The `d` has type `unsigned char`, so it cannot be negative (even after conversion to `int`, because of `printf`'s _default argument promotions_). In fact, you are right that in `d=~c` integer promotion also have taken place (in the same way, as I described in answer above), but assignment converts `int` to `unsigned char` back again. On the other hand, in the second case, `printf` function takes `int` argument "as-is" (i.e. `%d` format specifier is correct), so _default arguments promotions_ do nothing there.

Comment: For further readers: I updated my answer to reflect Marc's observion. You may find the original (shorter) answer in revision history. Hope everything is clear now.

Comment: Note that in some systems `unsigned char` could be promoted to `unsigned int` by the integer promotions (e.g., if `sizeof(int) == 1`), in which case the `printf` would invoke undefined behavior because it used the wrong specifier.

Comment: @T.C.: You are right, but let's assume (for simplicity) that we live in world where one byte consist of eight bits. I know that the Standard does not enforce it, but for instance the POSIX does.

Answer (score 27):

`char` is promoted to `int` in `printf` statement before the operation `~` in second snippet. So `c`, which is

```
0000 0100 (2's complement)
```

in binary is promoted to (assuming 32-bit machine)

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 // Say it is x
```

and its bit-wise complement is equal to the two's complement of the value minus one (`~x = −x − 1`)

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011
```

which is `-5` in decimal in 2's complement form.

Note that the default promotion of `char` `c`  to `int` is also performed in

```
d = ~c;
```

before complement operation but the result is converted back to `unsigned char` as `d` is of type `unsigned char`.

#### C11: 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment (p2):

> In simple assignment (`=`), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

and

#### 6.5.16 (p3):

> The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have
> after lvalue conversion.

Answer (score 17):

To understand behavior of your code, you need to learn the concept called ['Integer Promotions'](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) (that happens in your code implicitly before bit wise NOT operation on an `unsigned char` operand) As mentioned in N1570 committee draft:

> #### [§ 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators](https://is.muni.cz/www/408176/38744863/International_Standard_for_C.txt)
>
> 4. The result of the `~` operator is the bitwise complement of its
>      (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only
>      if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). **The
>      integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has
>      the promoted type**. If the promoted type is an " 'unsigned type', the
>      expression `~E` is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that
>      type minus `E`".

Because `unsigned char` type is narrower than (as it requires fewer bytes) `int` type,  - implicit type promotion performed by abstract machine(compiler) and value of variable `c` is promoted to `int` at the time of compilation (before application of the complement operation `~`). It is required for the correct execution of the program because `~` need an integer operand.

> #### [§ 6.5 Expressions](https://is.muni.cz/www/408176/38744863/International_Standard_for_C.txt)
>
> 4. **Some operators (the unary operator `~`,** and the binary operators `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `^`, and `|`,
>      collectively described as bitwise operators) **are required to have operands that have
>      integer type**. These operators yield values that depend on the internal representations of
>      integers, and have implementation-deﬁned and undeﬁned aspects for signed types.

Compilers are smart-enough to analyze expressions, checks semantics of expressions, perform type checking and arithmetic conversions if required. That's the reason that to apply `~` on `char` type we don't need to explicitly write `~(int)c` — called explicit type casting (and do avoid errors).

Note:

1. Value of `c` is promoted to `int` in expression `~c`, but type of `c` is still `unsigned char` - its type does not. Don't be confused.
2. **Important:** result of `~` operation is of `int` type!, check below code (I don't have vs-compiler, I am using gcc):

   ```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   int main(void){
      unsigned char c = 4;
      printf(" sizeof(int) = %zu,\n sizeof(unsigned char) = %zu",
               sizeof(int),
               sizeof(unsigned char));
      printf("\n sizeof(~c) = %zu", sizeof(~c));        
      printf("\n");
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```

   compile it, and run:

   ```
   $ gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic x.c -o x
   $ ./x
   sizeof(int) = 4,
   sizeof(unsigned char) = 1
   sizeof(~c) = 4
   ```

   **Notice**: size of result of `~c`  is same as of `int`, but not equals to `unsigned char` — result of `~` operator in this expression is `int`! that as mentioned [**6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators**](https://is.muni.cz/www/408176/38744863/International_Standard_for_C.txt)

   > 3. The result of the unary `-` operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer
   >      promotions are performed on the operand, and **the result has the promoted type.**

Now, as @haccks also explained in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28560396/1673391) -that result of `~c` on 32-bit machine and for value of `c = 4` is:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011
```

in decimal it is `-5` — that is the output of your **second code**!

In your **first code**, one more line is interesting to understand `b = ~c;`, because `b` is an `unsigned char` variable and result of `~c` is of  `int` type, so to accommodate value of result of `~c` to `b` result value (~c) is **truncated to fit into the unsigned char type**  as follows:

```
    1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011  // -5 & 0xFF
 &  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111  // - one byte      
    -------------------------------------------          
                                  1111 1011
```

Decimal equivalent of `1111 1011` is `251`. You could get same effect using:

```
printf("\n ~c = %d", ~c  & 0xFF);
```

or as suggested by @ouah in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28560549/1673391) using explicitly casting.

Comment: @haccks thanks, yes I mostly come here for learning  than participating and presently I am mostly working in python,django, web stuffs.

Comment: +int(PI/3) for actually quoting the relevant spec parts... no other answer actually explains *why* the promotion happens here! this->`Some operators (the unary operator ~, and the binary operators <<, >>, &, ^, and |, collectively described as bitwise operators) are required to have operands that have integer type.` made my day today.

Comment: @vaxquis thanks, - by the time I came to this post I notices that most answers were explaining "how results are different" , so I decided to add my answer and emphasize reason of "why so", -- at the time you read my answer  I was missing one more relevant from draft, now added.

Answer (score 12):

When applying the `~` operator to `c` it gets promoted to `int`, the result is an `int` as well.

Then

- in the 1st example the result gets converted to `unsigned char` and then promoted to `signed int` and printed.
- in the 2nd example the result gets printed as `signed int`.

Answer (score 10):

> It gives the op -5. why it didn't work?

Instead of:

```
printf("%d",~c);
```

use:

```
printf("%d", (unsigned char) ~c);
```

to get the same result as in your first example.

`~` operand undergoes integer promotion and default argument promotion are applied to argument of variadic functions.

Answer (score 8):

Integer promotion, from the standard:

> If the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all
>   of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type,
>   the operand with unsigned integer type shall be converted to the type
>   of the operand with signed integer type.